# How to push new object in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to push new object in an array? Whenever I run this code in react it kept on replacing the first object in the array.

```
   radioButtonVal = (e) => {
    this.radioid = e.target.name;
    this.radiovalue = e.target.value;
    this.radioButtonValTitles = [];
    this.radioButtonValFind = this.radioButtonValTitles.find(x => x.id === this.radioid);
    if(this.radioButtonValFind){
        this.radioButtonValFind.id = this.radioid;
        this.radioButtonValFind.value = this.radiovalue;
    } else {
        this.radioButtonValTitles.push({id: this.radioid, value: this.radiovalue})
    }
}
```

Output is ({object, object}) just replacing the current values

Expected output is ({object, object}, {object, object}...)

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: You assign an empty array every time you call that function..

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you assign an empty array every time you call the function

```
 radioButtonVal = (e) => {
    this.radioid = e.target.name;
    this.radiovalue = e.target.value;
    this.radioButtonValTitles = []; //right here you initiate an empty array
    this.radioButtonValFind = this.radioButtonValTitles.find(x => x.id === this.radioid);
    if(this.radioButtonValFind){
        this.radioButtonValFind.id = this.radioid;
        this.radioButtonValFind.value = this.radiovalue;
    } else {
        this.radioButtonValTitles.push({id: this.radioid, value: this.radiovalue})
    }
}
```

What you should do is keep radioButtonValTitles in your state, and refer to them later, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        radioButtonValTitles: [],
    };  
}
```

and then modify your function like this:

```
 radioButtonVal = (e) => {
    const { radioButtonValTitles } = this.state;

    this.radioid = e.target.name;
    this.radiovalue = e.target.value;
    this.radioButtonValFind = radioButtonValTitles.find(x => x.id === this.radioid);
    if(this.radioButtonValFind){
        this.radioButtonValFind.id = this.radioid;
        this.radioButtonValFind.value = this.radiovalue;
    } else {
        this.setState({
            radioButtonValTitles: radioButtonValTitles.push({id: this.radioid, value: this.radiovalue})
        )}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that @@